# C++ template function type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have this code:

```
template <typename T, void (*f)(T*)>
class callfn
{
  public:
  void operator()(T* obj) const
  {
    f(obj);
  }
};

void call(int* foo) {}

void test()
{
  callfn<int, call> fun;
  fun(1);
}
```

Which tends to work fine. the type `callfn` is however used all over the place, And I'd much prefer if I could call it like this

```
callfn<call> fun;
```

instead, without modifying the type of `call` Is it possible to arrange the `callfn` template/templates in such a way that it can deduce the `T` type from the type of `f`?

Comment: what exactly are you doing with this? RN it just makes a functor that is essentially identical to the function itself

Comment: The goal is to use it as a deleter function for `std::unique_ptr` as a type so I can pass in a function as the deleter, and not take the 4 byte overhead of actually passing in a function*

Comment: Why would this not have any overhead, if anything a functor would have a higher overhead, I would just use the fp

Comment: Also what's wrong with std::function, if your so against fp's

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clarify.

    `void mfree(MObj* o);
    std::unique_ptr<MObj, callfn<MObj, mfree> mptr;
    assert(sizeof(mptr) == sizeof(MObj*));`

I hope that adds some clarity.

Comment: I really wish these comments allowed line breaks.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::unique_ptr<int,void(*)(int*)> p(i,call);`

Comment: Because then `sizeof(p) == sizeof(void*) * 2` It should be obvious why that could be undesirable in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you need to know the args for a struct or class only functions have template type deduction in c++.

Paper [n3602](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3602.html) seems to address this so it seems your not the only one who finds this annoying (me too). I don't know if it's going to be included but the paper at least means other people are thinking of it. [n6301](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html) will be able to eliminate the redundant typename you have for the non-type template param.

Another thing (also in c++14) is [`make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) which will be in the next standard. It is also probably relatively easy to code yourself.

As I noted in my comment it's unclear what exactly your trying to achieve with this, and if having to write the extra type is actually a barrier.

Since you made it clear in your comments that you need this to make a deleter for a `unique_ptr` I'm not sure what's wrong with.

```
std::unique_ptr<int,void(*)(int*)> ptr(int_ptr,deleter);
```

Comment: The goal of this is to not only make a deleter, but a deleter that doesn't take up any extra space per pointer, just like `default_deleter` does, yet with support for arbitrary functions.

Comment: @Arelius just use decltype, I'm gonna add a solution with that

Comment: @Arelius actually it really doesn't help that much, so you already have your solution but you just wanna type like 5 fewer letters is that the gist of it?

Comment: Correct, 5, or more or less depending on the length of an identifier.

Comment: It looks like this is something not possible, but actually addressed in [n3601](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html) I think that seems to be a more applicable paper.

Comment: @Arelius yes that would allow you to get rid of `typename T` and achieve the effect you want, n3602 would let you call it without any template params, so both helpful (neither necessarily standard)

Comment: Except n3602 wouldn't help in this exact scenario since I never actually pass `call` as a value type as a parameter to it's constructor. But is passed (necessarily) as a compile-time value to the template)

Comment: That is to say, without any template parameters `call` never gets used anywhere. This is necessary for the unique_ptr use-case

Comment: @Arelius my point about n3602 is unique_ptr won't need to be passed template params anymore

Comment: Perhaps update the answer to cite n6301? unless you think n3502 is somehow applicable in a way I do not understand?

Comment: @Arelius added it, I thought it best to leave both in

Comment: Yeah, I get that. Yet in this specific example, if it doesn't get passed to template parameters. It doesn't get passed anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it may be a non-solvable problem. But it's nice to have it confirmed.

Comment: @Arelius I was talking about in that comment you left `void mfree(MObj* o); std::unique_ptr<MObj, callfn<MObj, mfree> mptr; assert(sizeof(mptr) == sizeof(MObj*));` you could remove unique_ptr's template params

Comment: Yes, in the general case I could remove the `MObj` template parameter since I should assign it otherwise, but the second one is still needed to wrap around `mfree`, since it doesn't actually correspond to any value of unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on top of [aaronman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2167655/aaronman)'s [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19852224/1137388). Although you can't do with a template class alone, with some helpers, including a macro, it's possible:

```
template <typename T>
T deduce(void(*)(T*));

#define CALLFN(f) callfn<decltype(deduce(f)), f>
```

Example of usage:

```
CALLFN(call) fun; // instead of 'callfn<call> fun;' as asked
```

However, from the OP's comments this just a piece of a problem whose solution without this piece seems simpler.

If I understand it correctly, you want to create a `std::unique_ptr` for a certain type `T` with a custom function deleter `f` (of type `void (*)(T*)`) but you don't want the overhead of carring a function pointer in the `std::unique_ptr`. For instance, consider:

```
class MObj { /* ... */ };
void mfree(MObj*) { /* ... */ }
```

As said in an OP's comment we typically have

```
std::unique_ptr<MObj, void(*)(MObj*)> p1(nullptr, mfree);
assert(sizeof(p1) == sizeof(MObj*) * 2);
```

but using `callfn` we can save space:

```
std::unique_ptr<MObj, callfn<MObj, mfree>> p2;
assert(sizeof(p2) == sizeof(MObj*));
```

I believe the only annoyance with the solution above is the need of typing `callfn` and `MObj` twice. So, what about this:

```
template <typename T, void (*f)(T*)>
using light_unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, callfn<T, f>>;

light_unique_ptr<MObj, mfree> p3; // 1
assert(sizeof(p3) == sizeof(MObj*));
```

I also understand (maybe I'm wrong) that the intent is having something even shorter like

```
lighter_unique_ptr<mfree> p4; // 2
assert(sizeof(p4) == sizeof(MObj*));
```

and leave the compiler to deduce the type of the pointed object from `mfree`. As I indicated, this can be done with a macro but I don't think this is a good thing for two reasons:

1. It doesn't work if we have different overloads for `mfree` (say `void mfree(MObj*)` and `void mfree(Foo*)`).
2. A user will normally expect to see the pointed type of a `std::unique_ptr` in its instantiation and (eventually) its deleter. Line 1 above does show the type (`MObj`) but line 2 doesn't. Not seeing the type might be confusing for some.

I agree that the second point above is arguable (similar to the *should-I-use-auto* debate).

Comment: I like this solution, I may not actually end up using it just to avoid the macro. but it's indeed a very clever solution.

Comment: Couldn't you define `deduce` as a private class-static function within `callfn`, set up a member type-alias to `decltype( deduce(f) )`, and use (a pointer to) that type as the input to `operator()`? (You would use "`template <typename f>`" as the header for `callfn`, seeing if `f` fails to match in the call to `deduce`.)

Comment: @CTMacUser I'm not sure I understand you correctly but it seems to me that this wouldn't work. If we have `template <typename f> class callfn`, then `callfn` would need a type to be instantiaded with. However, the deleter, say `mfree`, is a function of a certain type but it's not a type itself. Therefore, `callfn<mfree>` wouldn't compile.

Comment: @CassioNeri, yeah, I just tried it. `f` is a value (a function pointer) not a type. So we would have to replace the "`typename`" with an actual function type, but we can't since we want that to be variable. We can't get around having two template arguments, short of a macro like `CALLFN`.